# Bracket with no statement

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I saw some code that had brackets with no ""if or "for" or "do" or anything but only a comment.

like this

> //some comment
>
> {
>
> int a=5;
>
> //and more code
>
> }

what is this?

note:I noticed that when using my IDE (code::blocks) it has that "-" on the left that when you click it, it hides all the code that are in the brackets. Is this the only use of the brackets with no statement?

Comment: In your example there's more than just a comment inside the block...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a scope. It limits the lifetime of any variables declared inside of it. For user defined types, this means a destructor call before exiting the scope.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo
{
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructor\n";  }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "before scope \n";

  {
    Foo f;
  }
  std::cout << "after scope\n";

}
```